# Diffeomorphisms, Isometries And General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, tensor-calculus

Apologies if this question is too naive, but it strikes at the heart of something that's been bothering me for a while.

Under a diffeomorphism $\phi$ we can push forward an arbitrary tensor field $F$ to $\phi_{*}F$. Is the following statement correct?

If $p$ is a point of the manifold then $F$ at $p$ is equal to $\phi_* F$ at $\phi(p)$, since they are related by the tensor transformation law, and tensors are independent of coordinate choice. ()

I have a feeling that I'm missing something crucial here, because this would seem to suggest that diffeomorphisms were isometries in general (which I know is false). (*)

However if the statement isn't true then it menas that physical observables like the electromagnetic tensor $F^{\mu \nu}$ wouldn't be invariant under diffeomorphisms (which they must be because diffeomorphisms are a gauge symmetry of our theory). In fact the proper time $\tau$ won't even be invariant unless we have an isometry!

What am I missing here? Surely it's isometries and not diffeomorphisms that are the gauge symmetries?! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: General diffeomorphisms are not isometries; only the diffeomorphism under which the values of the metric tensor are invariant at every point are isometries, by definition. However, the transformation rules for tensor fields are given by the same universal formula that works pretty much the same whether or not the diffeomorphism is an isommetry or not. The only difference between isometry and non-isometry is that a particular tensor field, the metric tensor field, is or is not invariant. In GR, all diffeomorphisms (or those that are trivial at infinity) form a gauge group (or its part).

Comment: @LubošMotl - Thanks for your comment! I already understand the difference between isometries and diffeomorphisms. My problem is that a general diffeomorphism doesn't preserve the metric, so will **not** necessarily preserve the proper time between events. But the proper time is an observable that's independent of frame! How on earth can we say that diffeomorphisms are a gauge symmetry if they are changing a physical quantity?!

Comment: The proper time is coordinate independent.  While it's true that changing coordinates changes the metric components, a proper time integral over a timelike path between two spacetime points will have the same value in both coordinate systems.

Comment: @sjasonw: I'm not talking about a coordinate transformation, I'm talking about a diffeomorphism. A diffeomorphism will genuinely change the metric itself, not just it's components. The components of the metric have no physical significance at all, because you have to choose a coordinate system in order to talk about them.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion.  Of course coordinate transformations are local diffeomorphisms of $\bf{R}^n$ so my comment might not be useless...  Consider the following.  Suppose I have a timelike path $\gamma$ between points $a$ and $b$.  Then I can use the diffeomorphism $\phi$ to get a new path $\phi \circ \gamma$.  I would think that the proper time of this new path evaluated with $\phi_{\star}g$ would be the same as the original proper time.

Comment: "How on earth can we say that diffeomorphisms are a gauge symmetry if they are changing a physical quantity"  they are a gauge symmetry in the sense that they preserve *Dirac observables*.  For the Diff group, though, these observables are rather restricted - things like integrals of various contractions of products of the Riemann tensor with itself.

Comment: @sjasonw - but isn't what you say only true for isometries?

Comment: @sjasonw - perhaps it's also true for geodesics, just not for general timelike curves. [This](http://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr5.pdf) seems to suggest so. Perhaps the proper time is only invariant for geodesics. Is this physically reasonable?

Comment: @EdwardHughes Actually, if $(M,g)$ is a spacetime, $N$ is a manifold, and $\phi :M\rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism, then $\phi$ is an isometry between $(M,g)$ and $(N,\phi_{\star}g)$.  So maybe that helps?  Also, I don't think it's reasonable that it could be true for geodesics only: arbitrary timelike curves are built out of infinitesimal geodesics.

Comment: @sjasonw No - isn't $\phi$ only an isometry if $\phi_*g = g$?

Comment: @EdwardHughes What you said is correct if we are talking about an isometry between $(M,g)$ and itself.  I was talking about an isometry between $(M,g)$ and a different spacetime $(N,\phi_{\star}g)$ (you can take $M=N$ if you want to).

Comment: @sjasonw Ah right - so there's no contradiction in my original post, because a diffeomorphism is naturally an isometry onto the space with the pushed forward metric? If that's right and you want to write up your comments as an answer I'd be happy to upvote and accept! Many thanks!

Comment: @sjasonw To be more specific - am I right to conclude that statement (*) is correct but conclusion (**) flawed in my OP? I think that's what your comment implies :)

Comment: Well the statement is the right idea I think, but saying that a tensor at $p$ is equal to one at $\phi (p)$ is not very clear.  As you know, tangent spaces at different points are not naturally isomorphic so there is no meaning to "equal".  However, we can use what we talked about above: the diffeomorphism $\phi$ induces an isomorphism between $T_p M$ and $T_{\phi (p)} M$.  Then we can certainly say that $F(p)$ and $\phi_{\star}F(\phi(p))$ are "equal".  I guess I'll put this in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If p is a point of the manifold then F at p is equal to ϕ∗F at ϕ(p), since they are related by the tensor transformation law, and tensors are independent of coordinate choice.

This is roughly true.  Initially, there is no meaning when one says that tensors at different tangent spaces are equal.  However, the diffeomorphism induces an isomorphism between $T_p M$ and $T_{\phi (p)} M$ (the isomorphism is nothing but the vector push forward).  The two tensors are equal with respect to this isomorphism.

> I have a feeling that I'm missing something crucial here, because this would seem to suggest that diffeomorphisms were isometries in general...

This is actually true in a sense that is relevant.  If $(M,g)$ is a spacetime and $\phi \in \text{diff}(M)$, then while there is no reason to think that $\phi$ is an isometry between $(M,g)$ and itself, $\phi$ is always an isometry between $(M,g)$ and $(M,\phi_{\star}g)$.

This last point saves your concern about proper time.  If $\gamma$ is a normalized timelike path between two events $a$ and $b$, we can always consider $\phi \circ \gamma$ as a timelike path in $(M,\phi_{\star}g)$.  You can check that the new path is normalized with respect to the new metric $\phi_{\star}g$.  The domains of the two paths are exactly the same so the proper time between $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ is the same as the original path's proper time.